# (Unity)Как заставить правильно двигаться камеру за игроком

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю "кенши"подобную игру, хочу, чтобы когда игрок зажимал колёсико и двигал мышь влево вправо, камера двигалась вокруг персонажа, при этом мой скрипт на передвижение делает, чтобы камера всегда смотрела ему в зад , из-за этого, если я присоединяю камеру к объекту прокрутка не работает. Что можно с этим сделать?
Вот скрипт на перемещение

```
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask ClickedTargetLayer;

    private NavMeshAgent MyAgent;

    public GameObject Player;

    public static bool Taked = false;

    private void Start()
    {

        MyAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Taked == true)
        {
            Camera.main.transform.parent = Player.transform;
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Camera.main.transform.parent = Player.transform;
                Ray MyRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hitinfo;
                if (Physics.Raycast(MyRay, out hitinfo, 200, ClickedTargetLayer))
                {
                    MyAgent.SetDestination(hitinfo.point);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Вот место, где происходит разворот колёсиком. Опять же привязать камеру к объекту не вариант.

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2) && MovementScript.Taked != false)
        {
                if (Input.mousePosition.x > lastMouseX)
                {
                Capsule.transform.Rotate(0, -150 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                }
                else if (Input.mousePosition.x < lastMouseX)
                {
                Capsule.transform.Rotate(0, 150 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                }
              lastMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        }
```

Comment: Отвязать камеру о затылка ?

Comment: Тогда она не будет летать за персонажем при движении. Она привязывается к заду при клике, когда персонаж идёт, а потом отцепляется. Тогда нужно переписывать код движения, а я не знаю как это сделать правильно.

Comment: @Cordis, ну так что, что то подскажите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. берешь персонажа и вешаешь на него пустой обьект. Даный обьект - это будет твоим pivot-ом под камеру.
2. внутрь даного обьекта размещаешь камеру и отдаляешь ее на нужном расстоянии.
3. отслеживаешь зажатие колеса мышки и отслеживаешь на сколько она сдвинулась да поворачиваешь пустой обьект-пивот на нужное расстояние. Камера будет поворачиваться вместе с ним.(фактически вокруг персонажа на равном расстоянии.)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, думал уже, что не смогу сделать. )  Как я сам не догадался. Так просто оказалось. Пойду делать.